# How do I know if a given curve requires a FpCurve F2mCurve or ECCCurve?

Tags: elliptic-curves

I'm trying to read a public key into Bouncy Castle (secp256k1) and need to choose from the following objects

```
        FpPoint;
        FpCurve;
```

or

```
        F2mPoint;
        F2mCurve;
```

or

```
        ECPoint;
        ECCurve;
```

Although it would be helpful if someone simply told me which object to use, what would be more useful is if someone can guide me through the general thought process in selecting any of the above objects for a given named curve.

Comment: Be careful what you use that curve for - it might not be safe. See http://safecurves.cr.yp.to/

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `EC` objects implement general elliptic curve properties, whereas the other 2 operate on specific fields. Since sec**p**256k1 is a prime field curve, you want the `Fp` objects. For binary field curves, you would use the `F2m` objects.

Note that NIST "K" curves are binary field curves, wheras secp256k1 is a "K" curve but over a prime field. Koblitz curves allow efficient mathematical operations.